# Add 'refresh datasource button' in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau Server, it is possible to refresh the DataSources using the button "Refresh" located in the Toolbar.

[image]

My client needs to add a button within the dashboard that can perform the same action, to "refresh the data sources" in order to see newly available data. (Note that they use the dashboard within a webpage, so F5 and ":refresh=y" are not options for them, unfortunately. And actually, I'm going to need to hide the toolbar).

Please happy to have your advice on how to add a refresh data source button within the dashboard.

Comment: Does the toolbar button actually refresh the datasource if you're using anything but a live connection?

Comment: Read about Tableau Server's JavaScript API

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the Tableau Extension feature. The sample files on [github](https://github.com/tableau/extensions-api/tree/master/Samples) actually include a data source refresh example called `Filtering`. Follow the [Tutorial](https://github.com/tableau/extensions-api/tree/master/Tutorial) to get started. I recently implemented this in a workbook and it works great. No need to code anything new.